# AUCTeX doesn't find errors with chemmacros and tables

Tags: emacs, auctex, chemmacros

When I run the following code, if I type C-c C-backtick after being notified of the presence of errors, AUCTeX says `no more errors` and it doesn't point me to the `&` in excess. The log file shows the error but AUCTeX doesn't point me to it. If I comment-out `\usepackage{chemmacros}` it works flawlessly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  &&& \\ % One too much
  &&
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

### Update:

I have Emacs 24.5.1, AUCTeX 11.91.0, Chemmacros v5.8b.
I've tried with an init file consisting only of

```
(require 'reftex)
```

and the behaviour is the same.

Comment: it worked for me as far as I can tell. You probably need exact emacs and auctex version numbers and probably more of a question  for the emacs stackexchange than here,

Comment: Works for me as well (Emacs 24.3.1 with AUCTeX 11.87)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's also suited for this site, since [giordano](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31416/giordano) monitors the [tag:auctex] tag.

Comment: @clemens See my updated question

Comment: @DavidCarlisle see update. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ArchStanton I can't help: I am a mere user of AUCTeX.